# Trying to play an RTMP stream using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp, exoplayer

I have this code:

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.simple_player);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    RtmpDataSourceFactory rtmpDataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();
 MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(rtmpDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://player.cdnmedia.tv/embed/a77aa67c"));
player.prepare(videoSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

This is my graddle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.company.streaming"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.7.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I get a crash with this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource.addTransferListener(com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.TransferListener)"
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource.createPeriod(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:246)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource.createPeriod(ExtractorMediaSource.java:354)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodHolder.createMediaPeriod(MediaPeriodHolder.java:417)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodHolder.<init>(MediaPeriodHolder.java:92)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodQueue.enqueueNextMediaPeriod(MediaPeriodQueue.java:149)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.maybeUpdateLoadingPeriod(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1623)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.updatePeriods(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1492)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:552)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:326)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I have followed tutorials, and searched the net to see if someone has the same problem that I do, with no result.

Any guide?

Thank you.

EDIT:

After adding the code Martin told me, I am receiving this now:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
net.butterflytv.rtmp_client.RtmpClient$RtmpIOException
    at net.butterflytv.rtmp_client.RtmpClient.open(RtmpClient.java:56)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.rtmp.RtmpDataSource.open(RtmpDataSource.java:57)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:841)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractMethodError` `abstract method "void com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource.addTransferListener(com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.TransferListener)` means that you have to implement abstract method [`DataSource`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DataSource.html) / [`RtmpDataSource`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ext/rtmp/RtmpDataSource.html) `.addTransferListener(TransferListener)`. Class [`DefaultBandwidthMeter`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultBandwidthMeter.html) would already implement `interface` [`TransferListener`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/index.html?com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/TransferListener.html) (this could be any other class, which does that).

Try the other one constructor:

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
```

Comment: I have done that, and now I am receiving "Source error". The streaming is not currently online, is that the reason maybe? If I paste the URL in a browser, I see colour bars, which I dont see in the app. I am waiting for the client to start a test streaming, and see if it works if there is some content actually streaming. Will update with the results, and will accept answer if it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Trying in Postman returns "Could not get any response". Disallowing SSL certification in the settings of Postman looks like I get something (html code).

Comment: The client started streaming, and I am receiving Source error. Updating my question.